# Building Django Activity Feed using Redis

Tags: ios, django, json, redis, feed

How can one build an activity feed using Django & Redis?

Example: In the 'Home' section of my iOS app, I would like to fill it with activities generated by users via JSON.

**Bob liked Kyle's poem.**

**Bob started following Kyle.**

**Bob liked 6 poems**           ------>(all six poems aggregated together in the feed)

**Bob commented on Kyle's poem: Beautiful piece!**

How can I go about doing this? If the question is not clear, please let me know so that I can make it clearer for you and others who come across this post and may find it useful! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing requires

1. aggregation logic (which you can write in python since your main framework is django)
2. a task queue running in the background which executes these aggregation logic
3. denormalized and duplicated data in your redis database, repeating data which are relational in your main database, such as your postgresql database

You can breakdown your activity feed into its components which are aggregated together on redis but are related to each other on your relational database.

`Bob` and `Kyle` and `poems` and `Beautiful piece` are objects, respectively user object, user object, a poem object and a comment object which are stored in your relational database.

Your activity types are "following", "liked", "commented".

You can then write your python logic to aggregate them into a single feed item which is stored in your redis database and each of these feed item is composed of objects and activity types (and a time stamp in which that activity happens).

That's the primary design consideration to get started.

Here's a good example - https://github.com/SupermanScott/redis-activity-example

Comment: Thanks for the reply Calvin, that is the example I came across and started following. I'm not quite sure as to how I can run the celeryd service. In this case Celeryd is the task queue running the background. I'm also unsure of how to implement all of this into Django! Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you seen this - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery ? It has a step-by-step guiding you to installing all of celery's dependencies and setting up your celery task server to work with your django application.

Comment: Yes I've come across that link as well. I'm going to try it right now.  Hopefully if I run into any issues, I can contact you again. Thanks Calvin

Comment: So Calvin, I followed all the steps as you suggested. I am using Redis as my broker. I use the command: $ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info but I recieve an error. "Consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish connection.."

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#celerytut-broker

Comment: Is your Redis process running?

Comment: Hey, yeah I ran the command: "redis-cli ping" and it returned PONG so it is working, I'm not quite sure why it's not connecting

Comment: Have you specified all the settings in your django `settings.py` file?  Reference detailed tutorial here - http://trespams.com/2011/04/03/celery-redis-and-django/

Comment: I modified all the settings in the setting.py as follows:

Comment: however when I run the command: $ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info, it says ImportError: No module named tasks". My tasks.py is on my Desktop however

Comment: I am following this tutorial here: ttp://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#celerytut-broker

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20365/discussion-between-rgjeya-and-calvin-cheng)

Answer (score 1):

Stream-Framework is an open-source library made to build feeds and supports both Redis and Cassandra as storage backends.

You can check it out on [github](http://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework)

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of Stream-Framework

Comment: I have several questions about your feedly project, how can I reach you?